# update manager saying error on line 59 in sources list

Tags: update-manager, unity-2d, software-sources

Can't figure out where my problem is.

I tried to post my sources list but apparently Ubuntu won't let a new user post more then two hyperlinks so yea any suggestions on how to post that.

Comment: paste it at http://www.pastebin.com and copy-paste here the link from the address bar

Comment: The Update manager is telling you what's wrong, open the sources file with gedit and look for the error.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to edit your sources.list

open a terminal and make a copy of the sources.list

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
```

now edit the file

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

move to line 59 and compare that line with the others. SOMETHING IS WRONG HERE
a basic line will appear as this example:
deb-src http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted

If you are unsure of the correction that needs to be performed then you may comment that line out using "#" it would then appear as this:

#deb-src http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted

once the line is edited you can save and resume the update

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

please post back any errors or use pastebin and report